# echo backspace switch creates newline

Tags: bash

I understand

```
\n = new line or carriage return
\b = move cursor to the left once (does not delete anything)
```

When you put those two together in this command:

```
read -p "$(echo -e 'Enter your age: \n\b')"
```

That outputs:

```
Enter your age:
_
```

With _ being your cursor asking for an input.

**My Question**: If I remove the \b switch, the cursor will **not** be on a newline.  Can someone explain to me how this works?

Answer (score 5):

Trailing newlines are removed from `$()` command substitutions. Quoth the manpage:

> Command substitution allows the output of a command to replace the command name.  There are two forms:
>
> ```
>          $(command)
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
>          `command`
> ```
>
> Bash performs the expansion by executing `command` and replacing the command substitution with the  standard  output  of  the command, **with any trailing newlines deleted.** (...)

(Emphasis mine).

A way to achieve the same behavior without `\b` is to use bash-specific `$''` strings:

```
read -p $'Enter your age:\n'
```

Or to just put a newline inside a quoted string:

```
read -p 'Enter your age:
'
```

The formatting isn't pretty, but it'll also work.

Answer (score 1):

(Just for information when I run your `\b` version my cursor is on the end of the first line not at the start of the second line but that's likely just a terminal difference.)

By way of illustration compare this:

```
$ printf "$(echo -e 'Enter your age: \n ')_" | xxd
0000000: 456e 7465 7220 796f 7572 2061 6765 3a20  Enter your age:
0000010: 0a20 5f                                  . _
```

and this:

```
$ printf "$(echo -e 'Enter your age: \n\b')_" | xxd
0000000: 456e 7465 7220 796f 7572 2061 6765 3a20  Enter your age:
0000010: 0a08 5f                                  .._
```

To this:

```
$ printf "$(echo -e 'Enter your age: \n')_" | xxd
0000000: 456e 7465 7220 796f 7572 2061 6765 3a20  Enter your age:
0000010: 5f                                       _
```

Notice the `0a20` in the first output? That's the newline and space from our pattern.

Notice the `0a08` in the second output? That's the newline and backspace from our pattern.

Now look at the third output. We don't have any character after the newline so we don't see `20` or `08` in that output which makes sense but where did the newline go?

Turns out this is a "feature" of [Command Substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution).

> Bash performs the expansion by executing command and replacing the command substitution with the standard output of the command, with any trailing newlines deleted.

So by putting `\b` *after* the newline you are protecting it from being deleted by the command substitution.

Wintermute covers the correct workarounds/solutions in his answer (you could also put the string in a variable and expand it in quotes on the `read` line to get the formatting on that line a little nicer).